# Wrapping the invocation of an @Endpoint-annotated Spring-WS endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-ws

(Java 6, Spring 3, Spring-WS 2, JAXB2, Tomcat 6)

I have a requirement to log the request and response XML to a database table. I would like to be able to *create* a record on receipt of the request XML and *update* the same record when the response XML (or fault) is ready. Is there a way to do this with Spring-WS 2?

I want to wrap the invocation of the endpoint prior to unmarshalling the XML so I can save request XML, invoke the endpoint, and finally save response XML. I would use the unique ID returned from the DB after saving the request XML to identify the record that needs to be updated with the response XML.

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Spring-WS EndpointInterceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoint-interceptor).

**Implement an interceptor.**

You have to implement the `org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointInterceptor` interface where methods to act on the request and response events are provided.

By accessing the MessageContext object, you can retrieve the request and response mesages (getRequest and getResponse methods).
You can also use the setProperty method to store information in the request moment that is accessible in the response to correlate information (e.g., the ID of the record to update in the DB for example).

**Configure the interceptor.**

The interceptor either can be configured for a specific request or globally for all the web services. I copy some configuration from the documentation:

```
<sws:interceptors>
 <bean class="samples.MyGlobalInterceptor"/>
<sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="http://www.example.com">
 <bean class="samples.MyPayloadRootInterceptor"/>
</sws:payloadRoot>
 <sws:soapAction value="http://www.example.com/SoapAction">
  <bean class="samples.MySoapActionInterceptor1"/>
  <ref bean="mySoapActionInterceptor2"/>
 </sws:soapAction>
</sws:interceptors>

<bean id="mySoapActionInterceptor2" class="samples.MySoapActionInterceptor2"/>
```

Comment: Yep, this is how I solved the problem but had not had time to post my answer. Thanks for posting. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can log the soap request and response by copying the following line in your log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing=DEBUG

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%c{3}] %m%n
```

You can get more information from this link http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/common.html

Comment: This logs to standard out, right? If so I've got that covered using an interceptor. But I don't know how to do it for the database.